# Nextjs: How to register the quill-blot-formatter to dynamically imported react-quill on client side rendering only?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, quill, react-quill

I am importing `react-quill` dynamically on the client side only using `ssr: false`. My functional component which is working fine, I want to add the `quill-blot-formatter` package to the `modules` part of my quill component.

My first roadblock is, I can't register this `quill-blot-formatter` with `Quill` as it shows:

```
ServerError
ReferenceError: document is not defined
```

This page is client rendered, therefore I don't understand where this error is coming from!

This is my code:

```
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
import BlotFormatter from "quill-blot-formatter";

const QuillNoSSRWrapper = dynamic(import('react-quill'), {
    ssr: false,
    loading: () => <p>Loading...</p>,
})

Quill.register("modules/blotFormatter", BlotFormatter);
```

Here, I don't understand how to bring `Quill` out of `react-quill` now that it's being imported dynamically. Therefore, I think that `Quill.register` isn't working. Now, how do I register `quill-blot-formatter` with `react-quill`? Following the *Next.js example with react-quill*, I am not even importing react-quill as `ReactQuill` as is the default export in the package.

Then I declared the `blotFormatter` module like this.

```
const modules = {
    blotFormatter: {},  // here
    toolbar: [
        [{header: '1'}, {header: '2'}, {font: []}],
        [{size: []}],
        ...
    ],
}

const formats = ['header','font','size','bold','italic','underline',...]
```

And used in the `render()` method like this:

```
export default function NewContent() {
    ...
    render(
        <QuillNoSSRWrapper
            className={styles.quillTextArea}
            id="quilleditor"
            modules={modules}
            formats={formats}
            theme="snow"
            onChange={handleTextChange}
            readOnly={false}
        />
    );
}
```

So far, this `QuillNoSSRWrapper` child component is doing it's job fine, but, how do I use the `quill-blot-formatter` in it's `formats`?

Answer (score 6):

### **UPDATE**

You don't need another useEffect to register module you can do it when you importing ReactQuill.

```
const ReactQuill = dynamic(
  async () => {
    const { default: RQ } = await import("react-quill");
    const { default: BlotFormatter } = await import("quill-blot-formatter");
    RQ.Quill.register("modules/blotFormatter", BlotFormatter);
    return function forwardRef({ forwardedRef, ...props }) {
      return <RQ ref={forwardedRef} {...props} />;
    };
  },
  {
    ssr: false,
  }
);
```

With this code you importing ReactQuill, register you module and pass ref that you can use later *see details below*. So with this code you now don't need any state. Additionally you can add custom loading function to dynamic [details here](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import#with-custom-loading-component).

---

After one day of searching i found the solution. First of all you import dynamic ReactQuill.

```
import dynamic from 'react/dynamic'
const ReactQuill = dynamic(() => import("react-quill"), { ssr: false });
```

Or if you want to pass ref like this

```
const ReactQuill = dynamic(
  async () => {
    const { default: RQ } = await import("react-quill");
    // eslint-disable-next-line react/display-name
    return ({ forwardedRef, ...props }) => <RQ ref={forwardedRef} {...props} />;
  },
  {
    ssr: false,
  }
);
```

> And then you can use ref like this `<ReactQuill ... forwardedRef={quillRef}/>`

So then after you imported ReactQuill on client side you need to register module i found this solution [here](https://dev.to/everenjohn/adding-quill-modules-into-reactquill-in-nextjs-4pkj) it's looks strange and i had no time to improve it but it's work. Here the code.

```
  const loadQuill = async () => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      const Quill = await require("react-quill").Quill;
      const BlotFormatter = (await import("quill-blot-formatter")).default;
      resolve({ Quill, BlotFormatter });
    })
      .then(({ Quill, BlotFormatter }) => {
        Quill.register("modules/blotFormatter", BlotFormatter);
        return;
      })
      .then((value) => {
        setEnableEditor(true);
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    loadQuill();
  }, []);
```

This code will execute on client side end register module. Also as you can see you need to declarate state enableEditor. And render ReactQuill only when enableEditor is true

```
{enableEditor && <ReactQuill ... />}
```

Looks bit wierd so maybe I will update it later